# Getting to my profile in Facebook for a self web scrapping project using selenium

Tags: python, facebook, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get to my Facebook profile using selenium for a self-web scraping project I am working on. I have already figured out how to log in, but every time I have selenium click on the profile button it sends me back to the homepage. I am using a chrome web driver btw.

I have tried this so far.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import os
import wget
import time

# bypass alerts
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

# specify the path to chromdriver.exe
# will have to be changed on each computer
driver = webdriver.Chrome('-enter path to chrome driver here-', chrome_options=chrome_options)

# open the webpage
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")

# target username
username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='email']")))
password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='pass']")))

#enter username and password
username.clear()
username.send_keys("username")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("password")

#target the login button and click it
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']"))).click()

# We are logged in

# target account button and click it
accountButton = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[aria-label='Account']"))).click()

# target profile pick and click it
profileButton = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[role='link']"))).click()
```

It does click the profile button but I just get sent back to the home page.

Comment: you would have to show minimal working code which we could copy and run to confirm that you click correct element.

Comment: Ok, I made the edit.